# The application of self-attention layer raised index error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

So I am doing a classification machine learning with the input of (batch, step, features).

In order to improve the accuracy of this model, I intended to apply a self-attention layer to it.

I am unfamiliar with how to use it for my case since most examples online are concerned with embedding NLP models.

```
def opt_select(optimizer):
    
    if optimizer == 'Adam':
        adamopt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-8)
        return adamopt
    
    elif optimizer == 'RMS':
        
        RMSopt = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=learning_rate, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-6)
        return RMSopt
    
    else:
        print('undefined optimizer')

def LSTM_attention_model(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, num_classes, loss,batch_size=68, units=128, learning_rate=0.005,epochs=20, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2,optimizer='Adam'):
   
            
    class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
        def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
            if (logs.get('acc') > 0.90):
                print("\nReached 90% accuracy so cancelling training!")
                self.model.stop_training = True

    callbacks = myCallback()

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(Masking(mask_value=0.0, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=recurrent_dropout)))
    model.add(SeqSelfAttention(attention_activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
    
    opt = opt_select(optimizer)
    
    model.compile(loss=loss,
                  optimizer=opt,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                        batch_size=batch_size,
                        epochs=epochs,
                        validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
                        verbose=1,
                        callbacks=[callbacks])

    score, acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test,
                                batch_size=batch_size)

    yhat = model.predict(X_test)

    return history, that
```

This led to `IndexError: list index out of range`

What is the correct way to apply this layer to my model?

---

As requested, one may use the following codes to simulate a set of the dataset.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout,Bidirectional,Masking,LSTM
from keras_self_attention import SeqSelfAttention


X_train = np.random.rand(700, 50,34)
y_train = np.random.choice([0, 1], 700)
X_test = np.random.rand(100, 50, 34)
y_test = np.random.choice([0, 1], 100)

batch_size= 217
epochs = 600
dropout = 0.6
Rdropout = 0.7
learning_rate = 0.00001
optimizer = 'RMS'
loss = 'categorical_crossentropy'
num_classes = y_train.shape[1]

LSTM_attention_his,yhat = LSTM_attention_model(X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test,loss =loss,num_classes=num_classes,batch_size=batch_size,units=32,learning_rate=learning_rate,epochs=epochs,dropout = 0.5,recurrent_dropout=Rdropout,optimizer=optimizer)
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Minimal reproducible example consists of all your imports, and how exactly you are calling your function as well. Rule of thumb for getting fast answers, someone else should be able to copy-paste your code and run it immediately without any tinkering (even trivial ones, like figuring out what to import). Otherwise, people are just going to move on to the next question.

Comment: @Ananda Alright, fixed it up. Thanks

Comment: If you try `print(model.summary())` after you add the BidirectionalLSTM, you can see that the output at that point is, `(None, 64)`. I don't think this is supported for `SeqSelfAttention` which expects a 3D input. So you need to add one additional dimension from the output of the step before it.

Comment: You may need to pass `return_sequences=True` to the `LSTM` layer so that it would output a sequence and in turn the sequence-self-attention could be applied on it.

Comment: @today I dont think that is the problem as it occurs after I put `return_sequences=True`

Comment: @Ananda May i know what kind of dimension should i add? It can't just be a column of  random values, right?

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I would rewrite the code -

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Bidirectional, Masking, LSTM, Reshape
from keras_self_attention import SeqSelfAttention
import numpy as np

def opt_select(optimizer):
    if optimizer == 'Adam':
        adamopt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-8)
        return adamopt

    elif optimizer == 'RMS':

        RMSopt = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=learning_rate, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-6)
        return RMSopt

    else:
        print('undefined optimizer')


def LSTM_attention_model(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, num_classes, loss, batch_size=68, units=128,
                         learning_rate=0.005, epochs=20, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, optimizer='Adam'):
    class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
        def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
            if (logs.get('accuracy') > 0.90):
                print("\nReached 90% accuracy so cancelling training!")
                self.model.stop_training = True

    callbacks = myCallback()

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(Masking(mask_value=0.0, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=recurrent_dropout, return_sequences=True)))
    model.add(SeqSelfAttention(attention_activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Reshape((-1, model.output.shape[1]*model.output.shape[2])))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

    opt = opt_select(optimizer)

    model.compile(loss=loss,
                  optimizer=opt,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                        batch_size=batch_size,
                        epochs=epochs,
                        validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
                        verbose=1,
                        callbacks=[callbacks])

    score, acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test,
                                batch_size=batch_size)

    yhat = model.predict(X_test)

    return history, that


X_train = np.random.rand(700, 50,34)
y_train = np.random.choice([0, 1], (700, 1))
X_test = np.random.rand(100, 50, 34)
y_test = np.random.choice([0, 1], (100, 1))

batch_size= 217
epochs = 600
dropout = 0.6
Rdropout = 0.7
learning_rate = 0.00001
optimizer = 'RMS'
loss = 'categorical_crossentropy'
num_classes = y_train.shape[1]

LSTM_attention_his,yhat = LSTM_attention_model(
X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test,
    loss =loss,num_classes=num_classes,batch_size=batch_size,units=32,
    learning_rate=learning_rate,epochs=epochs,dropout = 0.5,recurrent_dropout=Rdropout,optimizer=optimizer
)
```

These are the changes I had to make to get this to start training -

- The original issue was caused by the LSTM layer outputting the wrong dimensions. The `SeqSelfAttention` layer needs a 3D input (one dimension corresponding to the sequence of the data) which was missing from the output of the LSTM layer. As mentioned by @today, in the comments, this can be solved by adding `return_sequences=True` to the LSTM layer.
- But even with that modification,the code still gives an error at when trying to compute the cost function.The issue is that, the output of the self-attention layer is `(None, 50, 64)`  when this is directly passed into the `Dense` layer, the final output of the network becomes `(None, 50, 1)`. This doesn't make sense for what we are trying to do, because the final output should just contain a single label for each datapoint (it should have the shape `(None, 1)`). The issue is the output from the self-attention layer which is 3 dimensional (each data point has a `(50, 64)` feature vector). This needs to be reshaped into a single dimensional feature vector for the computation to make sense. So I added a reshape layer `model.add(Reshape((-1, )))` between the attention layer and the Dense layer.
- In addition, the `myCallback` class is testing if `logs.get('acc')` is > 0.9 but I think it should be `(logs.get('accuracy')`.

To comment on OP's question in the comment on what kind of column should be added, in this case, it was just a matter of extracting the full sequential data from the LSTM layer. Without the `return_sequence` flag, the output from the LSTM layer is `(None, 64)` This is simply the final features of the LSTM without the intermediate sequential data.

Comment: First of all, I would like to thank you very much for the time and effort you put. The codes will now output `ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.
I guess the `Dense` layer doesn't take in `None`

Comment: What data are you using to pass as input to the network? You probably need to make sure that the shape of the input data is the same shape as the random arrays created in the sample code. Specifically, it needs to be `(700, 1)`  as opposed to `(700, )`. The `None` dimension is just a placeholder for your batch size. When the NN is being run, it will not be `None`

Comment: I was trying to run your codes, which includes the randomly generated X_train

Comment: What verison of Python, Tensorflow, and Numpy are you using?

Comment: python = 3.8.0, Tensorflow = 2.2.0 ,numpy=1.19.4

Comment: @leo, thanks, there seems to have been a slight difference in the behaviour between tensorflow 2.4.0 (what I was using before) and 2.2.0. The fix should work on both the versions now.

Comment: Do you mean it should be working for tf 2.2 now? I just gave it a try but it is still the same. Shall I create an environment for tf 2.4?